# Get scraped time with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

i have this kind of values from a scraped page and i want to get it by regex:

```
4:00pm
16th-17th
1:30am
```

i have this expression to deal with the time and it's working fine:

```
([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9](am|pm)
```

is there a way to have a single regex where i can also include the matching for **16th-17th**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9](am|pm))|(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)-\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th))
```

Comment: i dont really know that it is possible to have to different exp:))

Comment: You use `|` in your regex to match two different things. How could you not know that it's possible?